# Is this a valid MySQL UPDATE query?

Tags: mysql

Just a simple question, is this a valid MySQL query? In particular, the `AND` statement.

```
"UPDATE table SET field1 = 5,field2 = 10 WHERE field3 = 20 AND field4 = 40"
```

When I execute this, it returns that 0 rows were affected when the entry definitely exists and should have been updated.

Thanks in advance!

**edit: Ah, I'm using mysql_affected_rows afterwards...does this not work for UPDATE queries? Is there a way to find out whether any records were updated?**

Comment: Belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the WHERE part from your UPDATE and try running using it with a SELECT. Like:

**SELECT * FROM** table WHERE field3 = 20 AND field4 = 40

Any row(s) now?

Comment: Is your table's name "table"?

Comment: The names match. I updated my question though, I think that may be my issue...thoughts?

Comment: May be the values were already 5 and 10 thereby not necessitating an update? As per the contributor "Ome Ko" in the following link http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php "There are no rows affected by an update with identical data"

Comment: Oh I see, so if the entry is a duplicate the rows affected function won't increment...I think that's likely the problem. So I need to do a SELECT query to check if the row exists, if it does, I need to UPDATE it, and if it doesn't, I need to INSERT it. I was hoping to do this without the SELECT query.

Comment: No, you need not do a SELECT. I am just explaining why you don't get the right count for number of rows affected when you use "mysql_affected_rows". The link suggests, you use the "mysql_matched_rows" instead.

Comment: I see. It's a bit rough, but I'll give it a go.

Comment: OK I duplicated that function in C++ and it works perfectly. Thank you for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Could you be using '=' instead of using 'LIKE' for comparison for string fields?